# Small addition to current code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class linecounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a line of integers ");
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = chopper.nextInt();

        while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(chopper.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

I am in a CS1 class learning the basics of Java and have a quick question, on this code could anyone tell me how i could get it to keep count of how many integers were typed in?
Thank you

Comment: add counter in while loop and increment it every iteration

Comment: You can add a variable:
Integer counter;
while (chopper.hasNextInt()) 
{
counter+=1;
System.out.println(chopper.nextInt());
}

System.out.println("The total of integer numbers is: " + counter);

Comment: So, you tried to solve it yourself for 6 minutes? I would suggest that you give a little more effort instead of immediately posting here.

Comment: Please read the official tutorial on [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), it is concise and well-written and will give you all the tools you need to solve this problem. Your question is extremely basic and you really need to familiarize yourself with these concepts before continuing with your CS course.

Answer (score 3):

above your while loop, declare:

```
int count = 0;
```

then in your while loop use
    count++;

This will start you at 0 and every time it increments the count

Comment: +1 for giving a good description without actually doing the OP's work for them.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a counter to the while loop.

```
 int counter = 0;
    while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
         counter++;
         System.out.println(chopper.nextInt());

    }
  System.out.println(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cases that you have integer numbers, double numbers and you only need count the integer numbers, you can use:

```
public class linecounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a line of integers ");
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = chopper.nextInt();
        int counter = 0;
        while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(chopper.nextInt());
            String myCurrentArg = chopper.nextInt();
            if(isInteger(myCurrentArg) ){
                        counter++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The number of integer arguments are: " + counter);
    }

    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        return isInteger(s,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but for some reason it skips the first number and fails to print it out and include it in the counting.

Comment: Try the function isInteger without static